# How to find a formatted number in a string?

Tags: c++, string

If I have a string, and I want to find if it contains a number of the form XXX-XX-XXX, and return its position in the string, is there an easy way to do that?

XXX-XX-XXX can be any number, such as 259-40-092.

Comment: Regular expressions is the key

Comment: Since it's very simple, maybe you can also write you function your self or use sscanf. Not very clean, but It will be fast, and it avoids to link with a regexp lib.

Comment: sscanf isn't very good in finding stuff in unknown context. Consider the sting "1234-12-123". It clearly contains "234-12-123" but sscanf really can't find that.

Answer (score 4):

This is usually a job for a regular expression. Have a look at the [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) library for example.

Answer (score 0):

I did this before....

Regular Expression is your superhero, become his friend....

```
//Javascript
var numRegExp = /^[+]?([0-9- ]+){10,}$/;
if (numRegExp.test("259-40-092")) {
  alert("True - Number found....");
else 
  alert("False - Not a Number");
}
```

To give you a position in the string, that will be your homework. :-)
The regular expression in C++ will be...

```
char* regExp = "[+]?([0-9- ]+){10,}";
```

Use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) for this instance.

Comment: I am not sure, but doesn't your regular expression also match stuff like 1234567890 ?

Comment: yes and it also includes international numbers such as +25XXXXXXXX or 259 40 092.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want regexes, here's an algorithm:

```
Find the first -
LOOP {
  Find the next -
  If not found, break.
  Check if the distance is 2
  Check if the 8 characters surrounding the two minuses are digits
  If so, found the number.
}
```

Not optimal but but the scan speed will already be dominated by the cache/memory speed. It can be optimized by considering on what part the match failed, and how. For instance, if you've got "123-4X-X............", when you find the X you know that you can skip ahead quickly. The second - preceding the X cannot be the first - of a proper number. Similarly, in "123--" you know that the second - can't be the first - of a number either.